# How can I refactor this Ruby and Rails code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I refactor this code?

```
if env["rack.request.form_hash"] && env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"]
  env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"]=env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"].gsub("\r\n",'')
end
```

Comment: shouldn't _env_ be treated as read-only? it's like "params", you can modify it, but you *shouldn't*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"] = env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"].gsub("\r\n",'') rescue nil
```

or with in place editing

```
env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"].gsub!("\r\n",'') rescue nil
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, it would be nice to know the reason of the downvote.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted it, but it might be because of the `rescue nil`. That can cloak exceptions in non-obvious ways so I use it very seldom and carefully, but I'd assume you already knew that.

Comment: I normally avoid `rescue nil` because it can be abused, but there's nothing wrong with using it when you actually know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

if you have the [andand](https://github.com/raganwald/andand) gem, you can skip the check and go straight to:

```
env["rack.request.form_hash"]["authenticity_token"].andand.gsub("\r\n",'')
```

Comment: isn't a "andand" missing between the hash fetches?

Answer (score 0):

The hash indexes seem to be reused everywhere, maybe you can start there.

```
   key1 = "rack.request.form_hash"
   key2 = "authenticity_token"
   env[key1] && env[key1][key2]
```

Nothing clever, but significantly shortens the line.

Something like this could work:

```
    env[key1][key2].gsub!('\r\n','') if env.has_key?(key1) && env[key1].has_key?(key2)
```

Comment: env[key1][key2] would suffice, since it won't be true if env[key1] was nil in the first place, right? just gotta catch that exception

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
if (rrf = env["rack.request.form_hash"]) && rrf_at = rrf["authenticity_token"] then rrf_at.gsub!("\r\n",'') end
```

or similar but shorter:

```
rrf_at.gsub!("\r\n",'') if (rrf = env["rack.request.form_hash"]) && rrf_at = rrf["authenticity_token"]
```

It's DRY, concise and does not use rescue "hacks" ;-D

Answer (score 0):

Rather then using `andand` or `try`, I would do:

```
if env.fetch("rack.request.form_hash", {})["authenticity_token"].to_s.gsub("\r\n",'')
```

or add `to_hash` to the inventory of useful `NilClass` methods (`to_a`, `to_s`, `to_i`, etc):

```
class NilClass; def to_hash; {} end end
```

and do:

```
if env["rack.request.form_hash"].to_hash["authenticity_token"].to_s.gsub("\r\n",'')
```